# 2009 Chevy Equinox Turn Signal

Tags: electrical, chevrolet, equinox

My 2009 Equinox turn signal lever is acting up. When you switch it to turn left you have to hold it down in order for it to work. It returns to neutral but won't stay on without holding it. The right side works normally. Do I need to replace the whole component or is there an easy fix?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to replace the entire switch assembly.

Replacing the switch should not be that difficult. You should be able to do this by:

- Remove the steering column trim covers.
- Disconnect the multifunction turn signal switch harness connectors.
- Depress the lock tabs on the multifunction lever.
- Remove the multifunction lever.

Replace in reverse. You should not need to pull the steering wheel or mess with the air bag to complete this. In this illustration, the steering wheel is removed to better show what is going on and where the switch is located. This shows the switch on the right side (should be the wiper multifunction switch), but removal will be the same as the signal multifunction switch on the left.

[image]

Comment: @AbramsRun - Glad I can help. If this answers your question, please consider marking it as the answer by clicking the check mark just below the voting arrows.